# how do you account for when TCP does not get all the bytes in one read

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I just read an article that says TCPClient.Read() may not get all the sent bytes in one read. How do you account for this?

For example, the server can write a string to the tcp stream. The client reads half of the string's bytes, and then reads the other half in another read call.

how do you know when you need to combine the byte arrays received in both calls?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> how do you know when you need to combine the byte arrays received in both calls?

You need to decide this at the protocol level. There are four common models:

- Close-on-finish: each side can only send a single "message" per connection. After sending the message, they close the sending side of the socket. The receiving side keeps reading until it reaches the end of the stream.
- Length-prefixing: Before each message, include the number of bytes in the message. This could be in a fixed-length format (e.g. always 4 bytes) or some compressed format (e.g. 7 bits of size data per byte, top bit set for the final byte of size data). Then there's the message itself. The receiving code will read the size, then read that many bytes.
- Chunking: Like length-prefixing, but in smaller chunks. Each chunk is length-prefixed, with a final chunk indicating "end of message"
- End-of-message signal: Keep reading until you see the terminator for the message. This can be a pain if the message has to be able to include arbitrary data, as you'd need to include an escaping mechanism in order to represent the terminator data within the message.

Additionally, less commonly, there are protocols where each message is *always* a particular size - in which case you just need to keep going until you've read that much data.

In all of these cases, you basically need to loop, reading data into some sort of buffer until you've got enough of it, however you determine that. You should *always* use the return value of `Read` to note how many bytes you actually read, and *always* check whether it's 0, in which case you've reached the end of the stream.

Also note that this doesn't just affect network streams - for anything other than a local `MemoryStream` (which will always read as much data as you ask for in one go, if it's in the stream at all), you should assume that data may only become available over the course of multiple calls.

Comment: Or you could have a fixed length protocol where you know the length of the messages in advance.  Can't think of a useful example of the top of my head however :(

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: These are options *within* a protocol. How you detect the end of a message is only one part of the protocol.

Comment: @NPSF3000: That's a point, yes - I'll include that as an option.

Comment: @NPSF3000 do you mean the of the length header? Or the length of the message

Comment: With length prefixing, how can you be sure the initial bytes indicator the integer of bytes that need to be read, will be received properly if it too can be broken up into multiple reads?

Comment: @DanWebster: If it's a fixed-length length prefix, you can keep reading until you've read all 4 bytes (or however many it is). You should still loop, although I suspect you'll find plenty of code which doesn't, and "mostly" gets away with it...

Comment: @Dan I made something like that not long ago,

Comment: @Jon Thanks I understand now. But how many bytes should this prefix be and what encoding should it use? Should it be a short, an int, long, etc. This is probably application specific, but I actually have no idea how much bytes I am going to be sending yet, I am trying to make a small game.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses  You only need one of the four options provided by Jon if you do not know the length of the data ahead of time.  However, it's entirely reasonable to know the length of the data ahead of time due to some context.  For example, if I prefix every message by a 1 byte length header... that header itself is just a 1 byte message that doesn't need any other metadata[?] to be parsed.  If I was reading in a stream of ints... I'd know that each 'message' is only 4 bytes long and read as such.

Comment: @DanWebster: Are you going to be sending more than 2GB of data? (That's pretty unlikely.) If not, I'd just use 4 bytes, and read it into an `int`.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Part 2.  If I was hypothetically to design a protocal myself, as a game programmer my first instinct is to use a message type token.  From that token, I'd then know how to deserialize that message.  For example, if token 8 represents a byte byte int bool[8] (8 bits) I might know in advance that my message is 7 bytes long.  For datatypes that have an unknown size I'd do my length prefix *after* the message type.  So a list of int's is [list] [type(int)] [length] [int1...intx].

Comment: @NPSF3000 I didnt think of it that way I just made it that when there is a command you put length zero in it and I made my code like that that you could decide yourself what you want to do with all those bytes

Answer (score -1):

You should call `read()` in a loop. The condition of that loop would check if there is still any data available to be read.

Comment: That's only valid if the connection is going to be terminated by the sending side after the message has been sent. It doesn't work if you want to put multiple messages on the same connection.

Comment: There are only two ways of 'check[ing] if there is still any data to be read'. One is to check for EOS, which is invalid as @JonSkeet has noted above. The other is to call `available()`, aka `FIO_NREAD`, which just tells you how many bytes have already arrived in the socket receive buffer and can be read without blocking: it doesn't tell you how much data is left *in the stream,* because it doesn't know. Nobody can know. The sender could keep sending data forever.

Answer (score -3):

That is kinda hard to answer, because you can never know when data will arrive, and thats why I usually use a thread for receiving data in my chat program. But you should  be able to use something similar to this:

```
do{
     numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer,
                                              0, 
                                              myReadBuffer.Length);

     myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}",
      Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));

  }
  while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
```

Look at this [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx)!

Comment: Definitely *definitely* not. That will stop as soon as data isn't immediately available - so if one packet is delayed, you'll end up with half the data. (It's also ASCII only, which is almost never a good idea these days.) Even if `DataAvailable` blocked, you'd then be limited to a single message on a connection. This is *bad* code.

Comment: This is good info, even if it's wrong. It's a 'how not to do it'